# In what browsers query string (to prevent caching) works?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want append a query string "?v=123" to all .css and .js files to  forces the client's browser to download an updated copy of the stylesheet or script after new deployment.

**Will this work in all browsers?**
For me it is important to work in IE8,IE9,IE10,IE11,FireFox and Chrome.

But I can’t find information if this works in all browser.
If someone has experience please share with me.

Comment: Of course it will, because a different query string will make it a different URL – the browser _can not_ fetch that from cache if it was never downloaded before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not working in IE8 !
Today we had issue on server.
It's working in other browsers (IE9,IE10,IE11,FireFox and Chrome).

Answer (score 1):

Yep.

It's a query string parameter, which has been part of the [specification](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) since 1994:

> An HTTP URL takes the form:
>
> ```
> http://<host>:<port>/<path>?<searchpart>
> ```
>
> where  and  are as described in Section 3.1. If : is
>   omitted, the port defaults to 80.  No user name or password is
>   allowed.   is an HTTP selector, and  **is a query
>   string**. The  is optional, as is the  and its
>   preceding "?". If neither  nor  is present, the "/"
>   may also be omitted.